# Angular 2 - child component property not retaining state

Tags: angular

I have a bit a problem that has resulted in a fair amount of head scratching. Hoping you can help. A child component contains a button which toggles one of it's boolean properties. The change occurs in the function as verified by logging the property value to the console before and after the change. But it seems to only happen in the function scope and the actual property value is unchanged. It looks like the function is operating on a local copy of the property value. Any ideas what is going on here?

Thanks,

Ryan.

```
// child.component.html

<button (click)="toggleProp()">Toggle </button>

// child.component.ts

prop : boolean = true;

toggleProp()
{
      console.log(this.prop); // call 1: true, call 2: true
      this.prop = !this.prop;
      console.log(this.prop); // call 1: false, call 2: false
```

Comment: Could you share the entire child component file? Because this should just work as you described it. There has to be something else going on :)

Comment: Where are you trying to access `prop` and finding it unchanged?

Comment: If I immediately call the toggle function again I get the same result but it should be the inverse of the original call. Plus the property is used to conditionally remove another element from the dom using ng if and nothing happens when the property is supposedly toggled

Comment: In your case the value of `this` is maintained, so `this.prop` is not pointing to some mysterious `function scoped` variable, it's pointing to your `Component` property, as you would expect.

Comment: I know what it should point to but in this case it doesn't. The component was created dynamically using the Component Factory Resolver. Any ideas what could be causing it?